# Pull line 'n' from userform textbox

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform from which a user can select a block of text to insert into the spreadsheet at the active cell.  The catch is that I don't want the rows to be resized or changed in any way.  I've sized the userform textbox so that it it wraps at the correct number of characters and me.textbox.linecount returns the correct integer.  The trick is pulling lines 1 through n onto the spreadsheet and offsetting with each loop iteration.  Can anyone make this work?

```
Private Sub cmdINS_Click()
    Dim insTEXT As String
    Dim nROWS As Integer
    insTEXT = Me.txtINS.Value
    If Len(insTEXT) < 91 Then
        ActiveWindow.ActiveCell.Value = insTEXT
    Else:
        Me.txtINS.SetFocus
        nROWS = Me.txtINS.LineCount
        For i = 1 To nROWS
            ActiveWindow.ActiveCell.Value = 'Me.txtINS LINE i  <---Help, please
            ActiveWindow.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Next
    End If
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each line has a carriage return/line feed you can do something like this:

```
Dim vLines As Variant ' Vector to hold lines
vLines = Split(insText, vbCrLF) '
```

Now you can read line by line, vLines(n)

Comment: Trying to make this work, but I'm not sure if me.txtins.value carries the CR's along with it.